# How to make an if statement with tokens?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, token

I am working on a "new code", I am a somewhat advanced programmer. I did my best, and this is what I want to do.

```
@Echo Off
For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%A In (Script.txt) Do (
Echo token1=%%a token2=%%b token3=%%c token4=%%d
)
```

I want to echo "Command Detected" If token1 equals System.Color.

Answer (score 1):

After the Echo, add

if "%%a"=="System.Color" echo "Command Detected"